# How can I monitor/record network stability in the background?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, monitoring, network-monitoring

I work in a building where the network connection regularly has issues, but the people responsible for the LAN refuse to acknowledge there is a problem, "because nobody else has complained, so it must be your computers".

Is there a way I can run some sort of monitoring in the background that will record metrics of the network connection - like dropouts, latency, speed, etc. so that I can prove where the fault lies, and prove whether this is a network issue or a PC hardware problem?

Comment: Ask them to setup SNMP traps on the PC's in question.

Comment: You can always use the Windows API, given you know how to code, you can access the network interface and get you data from then objects you can find in there, or downlod Microsoft's Network Monitor.